# How to predict a server size depending on the DB increase?

Tags: php, database, performance

I would like to predict the server size that will be needed in the future for my web application depending on the size of the DB.

---

For example :

If I currently have a 512Mb Virtual Private Server which is running my php web application and the associated MySQL database which store 1 000 000 records. And if I consider that this server is currently at his limit.

Would a 1Gb Virtual Private Server handle the same application with 2 000 000 records? or more? or less?

---

I would like to know if I can consider a linear function depending on the DB record number to predict my server size in the futur or something more complicated?

**I am looking for a simple model to predict the server size increase in the future depending on the amount of record increasing in our DB.**

Thanks for your help!

---

UPDATE : For this we can consider that the number of users will stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

That does not depend on the record count linearly, this also depends on the load. Are you using indices, caching? That may help if you want to stay on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the records usually doesn't come into play - it's more the size of the indexes used in your queries. If the commonly used indexes can't be kept in memory, performance will take a serious nosedive.